# Strange simulation result: Can a rectifier diode conduct when the output terminal is open?

Tags: diodes, ltspice, simulation, rectifier, ripple

How does the output voltage build up for the below circuit when the terminal is open? Does LTSPICE assume any default node capacitance which gets charged- Not sure what causes the discharge/ripple in output voltage?

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the diodes themselves have a capacitance.

Comment: And leakage resistance.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing "assumed". The diodes have a precise definition through their `.MODEL` cards, which makes them have a finite impedance when forward/reverse polarized. Since you have no load then the forward polarization cannot contribute due to the load but, the reverse will always be true (and you have two diodes in series, everytime).